# How to Mock Media Query in CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries

Because the browser width of a mobile application is so small, it's nearly impossible to read the Developer Tools (with Chrome). For debugging purposes, this is the least practical application for playing around with the site's HTML and CSS.

How do I handle this kind of "issue"?  Is there a way to trick the browser into believing that the width is still the width of a mobile application even though the width is much higher?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem as follows: Bring up the Developer Toolbar, click the button in the bottom left corner. Now the window pops out. That' all.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome developer tools, you can override the user agent to a mobile / tablet device as mentioned here.
http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/12/changing-user-agent-new-google-chrome.html

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is undock the developer tools so you have it in a separate window than the page you are inspecting